# jquery selector not working on a dynamic value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

For some reason my jQuery function is not working on a dynamic value.

I'm trying to show/hide content `("item-content")` when the user clicks on the span "Click here".

If I use not nested HTML, everything works fine, but for some reason, my function breaks when I use nested HTML.

```js
$('.item-content').hide();

$(document).on('click','.main .child span.item-title', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).next('.main .child span.item-content').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <div class="child">
    <span class="item-title" style="cursor:pointer">
       Click here
    </span>

    <div class="item-content">
        <div class="item-body">
                1
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="child">>
    <span class="item-title" style="cursor:pointer">
       Click here
    </span>

    <div class="item-content">
        <div class="item-body">
                2
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="child">>
    <span class="item-title" style="cursor:pointer">
       Click here
    </span>

    <div class="item-content">
        <div class="item-body">
                3
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with `non-nested HTML` ?

Comment: "item-content" belongs to div not span. Correct your script to $(this).next('.main .child div.item-content').toggle(); and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.next` looks for the next sibling, so in your code you don't need to specify the class of what you're looking for as you're just getting the `span` sibling, which is `.item-content`.

Working example:

```js
$('.item-content').hide();
$(document).on('click','.main .child span.item-title', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <div class="child">
    <span class="item-title" style="cursor:pointer">
       Click here
    </span>

    <div class="item-content">
        <div class="item-body">
                1
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="child">>
    <span class="item-title" style="cursor:pointer">
       Click here
    </span>

    <div class="item-content">
        <div class="item-body">
                2
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="child">>
    <span class="item-title" style="cursor:pointer">
       Click here
    </span>

    <div class="item-content">
        <div class="item-body">
                3
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector you are toggling is incorrect, as it is looking for a span called 'item-content'. It should be:

```
$(this).next('.main .child div.item-content').toggle();
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all make sure that the jQuery cdn library is initiated before the custom script on your page.
There are two ways to hide components by css and jquery both. I'm posting the css script too and it's better to hide using css.
Also there is no need for specifying the classes from top inside the click event for toggle, the next() function basically lookup for the next html component.

```js
$('.item-content').hide(); // if using css to hide than this line is not required
$(document).on('click', '.item-title', function(){
  $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

```css
.item-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="child">
    <span class="item-title" style="cursor:pointer">
       Click here
    </span>

    <div class="item-content">
        <div class="item-body">
                1
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="child">>
    <span class="item-title" style="cursor:pointer">
       Click here
    </span>

    <div class="item-content">
        <div class="item-body">
                2
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="child">>
    <span class="item-title" style="cursor:pointer">
       Click here
    </span>

    <div class="item-content">
        <div class="item-body">
                3
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Question has already been answered and accepted and you've just pretty much repeated the accepted answer. This adds no value as an alternative.